# Docker mysql_database is connecting with klassy_docker_build?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I've been having trouble connecting the issue with docker mysql images, which is generally connected and worked fine with my local machine, but it's not connecting with my docker build the image.

As you can see I've mysql_database, redies_cache, and klassy_docker_build. So I would know from you which configure is helps to connect the mysql_database service to the klassy_docker_build. While docker compose up it's not getting the database connection and it's failed.

Here is the docker file.

```
FROM node:18 

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y default-mysql-client && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y redis-server && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
```

Here is the compose file

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  mysql_database:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysql_container
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: ${MYSQL_ROOT_HOST}
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./klassyco_dev_klassy.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/klassyco_dev_klassy.sql
    ports:
      - '3307:3306'
    expose:
      - 3307
    networks:
      - klassy_backend_networks

  redis_cache:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis_container
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/data
    networks:
      - klassy_backend_networks

  klassy_docker_build:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      network: klassy_backend_networks
    container_name: klassy_backend_container
    image: klassy_image_backend
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: ${MYSQL_ROOT_HOST}
    command:
      - sh
      - -c
      - |
        npm run start:dev

networks:
  klassy_backend_networks:
    external: true
    name: klassy_backend_networks

volumes:
  mysql_data:
  redis_data:
```

I would like to know Which configuration will help me to connect the mysql_database service to the klassy_docker_build? While docker composes up.

Comment: Is it specifically the `docker-compose build` step that's having trouble?  That can never connect to databases or other containers.  What specifically are you trying to do in the image build that requires the database?  (What would happen if you deleted the database storage, then re-ran the same prebuilt image?)

Comment: @DavidMaze Can you explain it bit more? Thanks

Comment: Imagine running `tar cvzf ...` to create a packaged copy of your application and emailing it to someone (this is not actually too far off of what `docker build && docker push` would do).  When the recipient tries to run the application, they won't have the same database you had locally.  What will be different?  What did you need to do with the database before you ran `tar` (or `docker-compose build`)?